Pulp. lpSum value dependencies in objective function
I am trying to select the best cable paths connecting each household (node "HH_") to the container (node "Cont_0") via pillar points (node "PP_"), that result in the minimal overall costs.
The overall costs are made up of Cost_node and total_edge_cos.
Cost_node is the number of selected pillar points multiplied by a node cost coefficient of 1000.
total_edge_cos is the distance of the selected edge multiplied by a coefficient, that is dependent on the number of selected paths that include this edge.
The attached image is an example of the outcome.

from pulp import LpProblem, LpVariable, lpSum, LpMinimize

# Initialize the optimization problem
prob = LpProblem("Optimal_Path_Selection", LpMinimize)

# Decision Variables ##############################################################################
# Create binary variables for each path and each edge
all_simple_paths_dict_binary = {}
all_edges_dict_binary = {}

for target_node in target_nodes:
    all_simple_paths_dict_binary[target_node] = {}
    all_edges_dict_binary[target_node] = {}
    
    for Nth_path, path in enumerate(all_simple_paths_dict[target_node]):
        var_name_path = f"path_{target_node}_{Nth_path}"
        all_simple_paths_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path] = LpVariable(var_name_path, cat=LpBinary)
        
        all_edges_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path] = []
        for i in range(len(path) - 1):
            var_name_edge = f"edge_{target_node}_{Nth_path}_{i}"
            all_edges_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path].append(LpVariable(var_name_edge, cat=LpBinary))


# Binary variables for nodes
node_vars = {node: LpVariable(f"node_{node}", cat=LpBinary) for node in set_of_nodes}

# Binary indicator variable for edge selection
edge_selected_indicator = {edge: LpVariable(f"edge_selected_indicator_{edge}", cat=LpBinary) for edge in set_of_edges}

# Binary indicator variable for node selection
pp_selected_indicator = {node: LpVariable(f"PP_selected_indicator_{node}", cat=LpBinary) for node in set_of_PP_nodes}

# store Binary variables corresponding to the same edge
edge_occurrences = {edge: {'variables': [], 'references': []} for edge in set_of_edges}
for target_node in target_nodes:
    for Nth_path, path in enumerate(all_simple_paths_dict[target_node]):
        for i in range(len(path) - 1):
            edge = (path[i], path[i + 1])
            edge_occurrences[edge]['variables'].append(all_edges_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path][i])
            edge_occurrences[edge]['references'].append((target_node, Nth_path))

# Constraints ##############################################################################
# Each target node should have exactly one selected path
for target_node in target_nodes:
    prob += lpSum(all_simple_paths_dict_binary[target_node].values()) == 1

# Connectivity constraints between paths, edges, and nodes
for target_node in target_nodes:
    for Nth_path, path in enumerate(all_simple_paths_dict[target_node]):
        for i, edge in enumerate(zip(path[:-1], path[1:])):
            prob += all_edges_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path][i] == all_simple_paths_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path]
            prob += edge_selected_indicator[edge] >= all_simple_paths_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path]
            
        for node in path:
            prob += node_vars[node] >= all_simple_paths_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path]
            if node in set_of_PP_nodes:
                prob += pp_selected_indicator[node] >= all_simple_paths_dict_binary[target_node][Nth_path]

# Objective Function ##############################################################################
node_cost_coeff = 1000  # Euro per node
Cost_node = node_cost_coeff * lpSum(pp_selected_indicator.values())

# Define cable ampacity requirements and cost function
cable_ampacity_requirement = 13 #[A]

thresholds = [0, 15, 30, 50, 65] 
edge_cost_coeff = costs = [0,2.65, 4, 7, 10]

# Function to calculate edge cost based on the selected cost coefficients
def calculate_edge_cost(edge, occ_info, thresholds, costs):
    edge_occ_sum = lpSum(occ_info['variables'])
    distance = G_copy[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight']
    for i in range(len(thresholds) - 1):
        if edge_occ_sum * cable_ampacity_requirement <= thresholds[i]:
            return costs[i] * distance
    # Handle the case where edge_occ_sum is greater than the last threshold
    return costs[-1] * distance

# Example usage within your code
total_edge_cost = 0.0
for edge, occ_info in edge_occurrences.items():
    edge_cost = calculate_edge_cost(edge, occ_info, thresholds, costs)
    total_edge_cost += edge_cost

    

# Define the objective function
prob += Cost_node + total_edge_cost

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Print the optimized objective value
# Initialize variables to store selected edge information
selected_edges_info = {}
total_edge_cost = 0.0
TOTAL_COST = 0

# Function to calculate edge cost based on the selected cost coefficients
def calculate_edge_cost(edge, occ_info, thresholds, costs):
    edge_occ_value = sum(var.varValue for var in occ_info['variables'])
    distance = G_copy[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight']
    cost = 0
    for i in range(len(thresholds) - 1):
        if edge_occ_value * cable_ampacity_requirement <= thresholds[i]:
            cost = costs[i] * distance
            break
    return cost

# Iterate over edge occurrences
for edge, occ_info in edge_occurrences.items():
    edge_occ_value = sum(var.varValue for var in occ_info['variables'])
    if edge_occ_value > 0:
        distance = G_copy[edge[0]][edge[1]]['weight']
        edge_cost = calculate_edge_cost(edge, occ_info, thresholds, costs)
        total_edge_cost += edge_cost
        redundancy = edge_occ_value  # Redundancy equals the number of cables in this context
        TOTAL_COST += total_edge_cost
        # Store the edge information with only the numeric cost value
        selected_edges_info[edge] = {
            'variables': occ_info['variables'],
            'occurrences': edge_occ_value,
            'references': occ_info['references'],
            'cost': edge_cost,  # Store only the numeric cost value here
            'distance': distance
        }

total_node_cost = node_cost_coeff * sum(var.varValue for var in pp_selected_indicator.values())
print('total node cost', total_node_cost)
print('total edge cost', TOTAL_COST)
# Print selected edge information
print("\nSelected Edges Information:")
for edge, info in selected_edges_info.items():
    # Print only the numeric cost value
    print(f"{edge} : cost: {info['cost']}, distance: {info['distance']}, occurrences: {info['occurrences']}")

In the case of the image, only one PP node is selected, thus the cost_node = 1* 1000.
In the case of the image, 4 selected paths include the edge ('Cont_0', 'PP_3'). 4 x cable_ampacity_requirement = 52, which is greater than the value 50 corresponding to thresholds[2], and is less than 65 corresponding to thresholds[3]. Thus the edge_cost_coeff[3], value of 15.06, should be multiplied by the distance. The following shoes the resultant results that are correct.
Status: Optimal
total node cost 1000.0
total edge cost 906.7390881679281

Selected Edges Information:
('PP_3', 'HH_3') : cost: 41.29350116765734, distance: 15.58245327081409, occurrences: 1.0
('PP_3', 'HH_0') : cost: 46.09130515253262, distance: 17.392945340578347, occurrences: 1.0
('PP_3', 'HH_1') : cost: 26.54809022113337, distance: 10.018147253257876, occurrences: 1.0
('PP_3', 'HH_2') : cost: 22.662708815682457, distance: 8.551965590823569, occurrences: 1.0
('Cont_0', 'PP_3') : cost: 390.93667342474583, distance: 25.958610453170373, occurrences: 4.0

Selected Paths for Each Target Node:
Target Node HH_0:
  Path: ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_0']
Target Node HH_1:
  Path: ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_1']
Target Node HH_2:
  Path: ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_2']
Target Node HH_3:
  Path: ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_3']

However, the results that prob.solve() prints out does not match the desired total cost as calculated above. It seems to only output the cost_node and not total_edge_cost. can someone help me fix this issue?
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                1000.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.02
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.02

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.06   (Wallclock seconds):       0.06

The following are the input:
All edges dictionary:
{'HH_0': [[('Cont_0', 'PP_0'), ('PP_0', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_1'), ('PP_1', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_2'), ('PP_2', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_3'), ('PP_3', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_9'), ('PP_9', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_10'), ('PP_10', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_11'), ('PP_11', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_12'), ('PP_12', 'HH_0')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_20'), ('PP_20', 'HH_0')]], 'HH_1': [[('Cont_0', 'PP_0'), ('PP_0', 'HH_1')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_1'), ('PP_1', 'HH_1')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_2'), ('PP_2', 'HH_1')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_3'), ('PP_3', 'HH_1')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_9'), ('PP_9', 'HH_1')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_10'), ('PP_10', 'HH_1')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_11'), ('PP_11', 'HH_1')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_20'), ('PP_20', 'HH_1')]], 'HH_2': [[('Cont_0', 'PP_1'), ('PP_1', 'HH_2')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_2'), ('PP_2', 'HH_2')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_3'), ('PP_3', 'HH_2')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_9'), ('PP_9', 'HH_2')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_10'), ('PP_10', 'HH_2')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_20'), ('PP_20', 'HH_2')]], 'HH_3': [[('Cont_0', 'PP_2'), ('PP_2', 'HH_3')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_3'), ('PP_3', 'HH_3')], [('Cont_0', 'PP_9'), ('PP_9', 'HH_3')]]}

All simple paths dictionary:
{'HH_0': [['Cont_0', 'PP_0', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_1', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_2', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_9', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_10', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_11', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_12', 'HH_0'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_20', 'HH_0']], 'HH_1': [['Cont_0', 'PP_0', 'HH_1'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_1', 'HH_1'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_2', 'HH_1'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_1'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_9', 'HH_1'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_10', 'HH_1'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_11', 'HH_1'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_20', 'HH_1']], 'HH_2': [['Cont_0', 'PP_1', 'HH_2'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_2', 'HH_2'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_2'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_9', 'HH_2'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_10', 'HH_2'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_20', 'HH_2']], 'HH_3': [['Cont_0', 'PP_2', 'HH_3'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_3', 'HH_3'], ['Cont_0', 'PP_9', 'HH_3']]}

Set of edges:
{('PP_3', 'HH_0'), ('PP_10', 'HH_0'), ('PP_1', 'HH_1'), ('PP_2', 'HH_1'), ('PP_2', 'HH_2'), ('PP_9', 'HH_0'), ('PP_1', 'HH_2'), ('PP_3', 'HH_3'), ('PP_12', 'HH_0'), ('PP_20', 'HH_0'), ('PP_9', 'HH_3'), ('PP_0', 'HH_1'), ('PP_11', 'HH_1'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_2'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_12'), ('PP_3', 'HH_1'), ('PP_10', 'HH_1'), ('PP_2', 'HH_0'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_3'), ('PP_3', 'HH_2'), ('PP_10', 'HH_2'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_0'), ('PP_1', 'HH_0'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_1'), ('PP_9', 'HH_1'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_9'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_11'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_10'), ('PP_20', 'HH_1'), ('PP_9', 'HH_2'), ('PP_2', 'HH_3'), ('PP_0', 'HH_0'), ('PP_20', 'HH_2'), ('Cont_0', 'PP_20'), ('PP_11', 'HH_0')}


Is the "network" always this simple?  Meaning is it always just a 2-point connection for each house?  H -> PP --> container.  If so, you could reformulate this to an easier construct.  The basis would be a simple variable to indicate which PP each house uses...  use[H, PP] ∈ {0, 1}

Not reproducible: other than the obvious omission of LpBinary, you're also missing target_nodes, set_of_PP_nodes, and G_copy.
